# Using Python for .NET in VS (C#) I get a file not found exception trying to import numpy

Tags: c#, python, wpf, visual-studio, python.net

I have been trying and trying to make python.net work in my WPF application. I did a pip install of python.net and reference python.runtime.dll in my VS project. 4/5 of the included embedding tests failed though I couldn't figure out why (EDIT: When run individually they all seem to pass. I'm still suspicious). Here's the most recent code attempt in C#

`PythonEngine.Initialize();
PythonEngine.AcquireLock();
PythonEngine.RunSimpleString("import sys\n");         PythonEngine.RunSimpleString("sys.path.append('C:/Users/mhames/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages')\n");
PyObject np = PythonEngine.ImportModule("numpy");`

Everything debugs fine until the last line, which throws a file not found exception. "Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'numpy' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Previously, I've tried the format recommended on the python.net page:

```
            using (Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
            dynamic sin = np.sin;
            Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));
            Console.WriteLine(sin(5));
            double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            /* this block is temporarily disabled due to regression
            dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
            dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, Py.kw("dtype", np.int32));
            Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);
            Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);
            Console.WriteLine(a * b);
            */
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

But this throws the exact same exception at the attempted numpy import. Before trying to run any python, the WPF application opens a system dialogue for a file selection, which I doubt is affecting anything but I'm desperate at this point. I also have both python 2.7 and python 3 on my computer, my PATH environment variable contains paths for both my versions of Anaconda, but I've also tried adding a specific PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH that point to only the python 2.7 folders.

Any ideas are much appreciated at this point.

Comment: Did you actually install numpy? `pip install numpy`. If yes, what does `import numpy as np` show in Python interactive session?